# Reduce pixels and size maintaining full image

Tags: jquery, performance

I had made a profile page and it is working perfectly. My problem is that when setting a profile picture with large size(`eg: 2950px X 2904px`) the jquery becomes slow(that is the animation) and the `css` hover but movement of mouse pointer is as normal.

Can anyone suggest any solution to make that jquery speed as normal.

Is there anyway to maintain the same pixels and load the jquery with same speed?

I tried an image with less size(`eg: 130kb`) with same pixels but no luck!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plz give some suggestions atleast comments...

Comment: Why are you using such a huge image for a profile picture, instead of one sized for the layout?

Comment: you appear to be asking your browser to animate 27 MB of data (9 Megapixels * 3 bytes per pixel) in real time.  What did you expect to happen?!

Comment: @Diodeus i didnt understand what do you mean by one sized layout?

Comment: @Alnitak i will not upload...but may be users can upload...Do you say to restrict this?

Comment: If in your page the profile image in 120 x 80, you should be serving up an image THAT SIZE, not one bigger than the user's entire screen, then depending on the browser to dynamically resize it.

Comment: @Diodeus i am resizing it to 220x190 px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a server-side image processing system that generates the profile image size, regardless of the dimensions of the image the user uploads. You then serve-up the resized image, NOT the one uploaded by the user.

Comment: Can you plz give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume you are not showing the entire image with it's full pixel count what you can do is use a hidden `canvas` element as a scratch pad to draw the original image into scaled. then grab the actual image from the canvas (`toDataUrl`) and use it as the src of your image element.